# Team Foundation Server Project Portal how to edit navigation menu?

Tags: sharepoint, team-foundation-server

We have a TFS 2012 server and project portal.

I can't figure out how to edit the left side navigation menu.

We have some other sharepoint sites where when I click Edit Page i can drag in webparts and stuff and there I can also edit the navigation menu by adding new pages or links to existing pages.

Anyone have any clue?

Comment: [Customizing Team Foundation Server Project Portals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff678492%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?

Comment: I've read it, and in the meantime i've figured it out. Its the Quick Launch Menu. Thank you! The confusion was due to my installation being in my native language meaning i had been looking the wrong place.

Comment: You should answer your own question then ;)

Comment: But i don't know what its really called in english all the menus and things :( i also don't know it this is applicable just to our sharepoint, because our other installations control the left menu in a different way.

Comment: I don't know TFS but it sounds like it is a Navigation Sidebar